# create fixed edge directional graphs in dot format with graphviz

Tags: graph, ascii, graphviz, dot, direction

Is there anyway to create defined fixed edges directional graphs using dot notation? the following dot notation (fig 2) generates an automated edges that are curved. It doesnt have notations which will generate directions with straight edges (fig 1). Been on hours trying to find anything close, any hints will be great. thank you.

```
# fig 1

box A --- box B
 |.  \
 |.   \
box C. \
       box D
```

```
# fig 2

digraph G {
    node [shape=record];
    
    rankdir="BT"
    a -> b              [color = red][arrowhead = diamond][taillabel = "tail"]
    b -> c              [shape = box]
    c -> a
}
```

[image: directedgraph]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what a fixed edge is, but if you don't want splines for edges, look at the **splines** attribute (https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/splines/).
Here is you graph with **splines=false**. You can also try **splines=polyline**.
You might also connect the edges to specific ports on one or both of the nodes (https://graphviz.org/docs/attr-types/portPos/).

```
# fig 2

digraph G {
    node [shape=record];
    // see https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/splines/
    // also look at ports  https://graphviz.org/docs/attr-types/portPos/
    splines=false  // or try splines=polyline

    rankdir="BT"
    a -> b              [color = red][arrowhead = diamond][taillabel = "tail"]
    b -> c              [shape = box]
    c -> a
}
```

Giving:
[image]

Comment: thank you! this gets it closer to what i am looking at. essentially it would be `portpos` as you have linked. what i would need is forcing the edges in a direction. I am trying to get a mapping of direction but using dot notation